# Angular 2 Error on fetch for javascript library (npm run build.prod)

Tags: angular, angular-seed, npm-run, angular2-localstorage

I am using the Angular 2 seed project from https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed, also installed "npm install angular-2-local-storage".
When I run the project by using "npm start" everything works fine as expected.

The problem comes when I run "npm run build.prod" per below. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
[15:07:52] 'build.bundles.app.exp' errored after 2.31 s
[15:07:52] Error on fetch for angular-2-local-storage.js at file:///C:/Dev/Web/node_modules/angular-2-local-storage.js
        Loading dist\tmp\app\app.module.js
        Loading dist\tmp\app\app.module.ngfactory.js
        Loading dist\tmp\app\main-prod.js
        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Dev\Web\node_modules\angular-2-local-storage.js'
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: How do you import this library ?

Comment: Btw do you run npm build on the same machine?